# How to get all records from thisa year onwards from LINQ to SQL model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Can anyone tell me an efficient way of returning this.  I have:

```
var allPrices = site.Prices.AsQueryable();
```

I now want to query allPrices from current year onwards.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var allPricesFiltered = allPrices.Where(p => p.Date.Year >= DateTime.Now.Year);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var currYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
var pricesAfterCurrYear = allPrices.Where(p => p.Date.Year >= currYear);
```